# Higher z-index does not change stacking order

Tags: html, css, z-index

What I am trying to do is, when the user hover on the image the image should reposition along the x-axis and it should reveal the `.content`. i have set `z-index: 10` to image and `z-index: 1`  to `.content` to make `.content` to be underneath the image. but `.content` still remains on top of the image. Please help me..

Here is [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/UfjNP/1/):

**html**

```
<div class="holder">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    <div class="content">
        <h3>hello there</h3>    
        <a href="#">view more</a>        
    <div/>        
</div>
```

**css**

```
.holder {
    margin-top: 130px;
    position: relative;
}
img {    
    display: block;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
    transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
    z-index: 10;
}
.content {
    background: blue;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
a {
    color: white;
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
}

.holder:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(90px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(90px);
}
```

Comment: `z-index` can only be modified in elements with a `position` other than `static`. Your `img` has `position: static` by default.

Comment: @JonasG.Drange Thanks a lot. I didnt know that before :)

Comment: corrected jsfiddle -- > http://jsfiddle.net/UfjNP/3/

Comment: In what browser are you not seeing the intended behaviour? Looks OK in FF/Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I corrected issue of my code  thanks to Jones G. Drange. As he pointed out in his comment
"z-index can only be modified in elements with a position other than static. Your img has position: static by default"

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UfjNP/3/)

```
img {    
    position: relative;
}
```